# Grails dynamic url mapping

Tags: grails

I have a product list I'm trying to create SEO-friendly URLs for.

Example

> domain.com/product/cell-phone-razor

"cell-phone-razor" is dynamic from the db

I have successfully achieved this behavior with the following code

```
"/product/$url"(controller: "product", action:"show")
```

However there becomes an issue when trying to map other actions non related to the page URL. Example I have an Ajax URL `domain.com/product/setPrice` which is being mapped to the show action.

I was able to work around this by adding the following to my urlmapping in addition to the previous mapping.

```
"/product/setPrice" {
    controller = "product"
    action = "setPrice"
}
```

Is there a better way to config my url mapping so that I don't need to add rules for every action mapping?

Answer (score 0):

In our application we use the following approach - not saying the perfect one. Basically we're appending URL fragments (that are happily ignored by search engines) to the SEO parts of the URL.

```
    name product: "/$productName-p$productId" {
        controller = 'product'
        action = 'show'

        constraints {
            productName matches: '.+'
            productId matches: '^[0-9]+$'
        }
    }
```

In your case the url should look like `domain.com/product/cell-phone-razor-p123455` where `123456` is the product id.

Comment: I'd like to try and do this without the use of id's. My product list is rather small, so I'm shooting for a super clean url. The prob is it forces all my Ajax calls to use the show action rather than the intended action.

Comment: Also keep in mind that mapping works on the first come first served basis (Grails tries to match URLs in the order directives appear in the mapping file) - if you move `/product/setPrice` to be before `/product/$url` then your setPrice will be called correctly.

Comment: Correct and that is what is currently working atm, however I was hoping there would be a dynamc solution that would prevent the need to have to list every action for that page in the url mapping. I'm glad you posted your example though, it is something I'll need in the future.

Comment: in the constraints, would there be a way to match and ignore certain urls?

Comment: The action itself can be mapped! For example `"/product/$action/$id" {
            controller = 'product'
        }`

Comment: still not clean enough, perhaps something like this "/product/$url"(controller: "product", action:"show") {
   constraints {
    url(validator: {
     return !(it in ['setPrice', 'setAnotherAction'])
    })
   }
  }

Comment: It's not as dynamic as I'd like, but at least your not having to define the entire mapping over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

Although not as dynamic as I'd like, but this seems to be the best solution.

```
"/product/$url"(controller: "product", action:"show") { 
    constraints { 
        url(validator: { 
            return !(it in 
                ['setPriceAction', 'setAnotherAction']
            ) 
        }) 
    }
}
```